# ошибка при написании SQL

Tags: python, sql

```
count1 = 0
while count1 < 100:
     id1 = random.randint(1, 1000000)
     uuidx1 = uuid.uuid4()
     letters1 = string.ascii_lowercase
     rand_string1 = ''.join(random.choice(letters1) for i in range(10))
     int1 = random.randint(100, 100000)
     insert_user = f"insert into [dbo].[GUID_Objects] (IACGUID, IACConnector_Guid, IACObjectClass, IACLastMod, IACPreferredLanguage, IACClientID, AlternateEmailAddress, Assistant, C, CloudLegacyExchangeDN, CloudMSExchArchiveStatus, CloudMSExchBlockedSendersHash, CloudMSExchRecipientDisplayType, CloudMSExchSafeRecipientsHash, CloudMSExchSafeSendersHash, Co, Manager, exportSourceAnchor, AS_AuthenticationAddress, Cn, Company, CodePage, Department) values ('{uuidx1}', '4D032273-BE6A-414B-940D-7F6FD53DA771', 'user', '7/26/2021', '{rand_string1}', '{rand_string1}', '{rand_string1}', '{rand_string1}', '{rand_string1}', '{rand_string1}', {int1}, {int1}, {int1}, {int1}, {int1}, '{rand_string1}', '{rand_string1}', '{rand_string1}', '{rand_string1}', '{rand_string1}', '{rand_string1}', {int1}, '{rand_string1}');" \
              f"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[GUID_objects_mv] ON insert into [dbo].[GUID_objects_mv] (id, IACGuid, Attribute, Value, IACConnector_Guid) values ({id1}, {uuidx1}, 'authOrig', 'python', 'GUID_connector') SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[GUID_objects_mv] Off"
     count1 += 1
     crsr.execute(insert_user) # ------ line 31
```

когда запускаю код получаю ошибку:
File "C:\Users\Пользователь\PycharmProjects\IAMCLOUD\scripts\expressions30\100_users.py", line 31, in 
crsr.execute(insert_user)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'b1687'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

не могу понять в чем проблема - подскажите!

Comment: Покажите текст запроса, получившийся в переменной insert_user  после сборки.

Comment: Вы подсказали где искать ошибку и я её нашел, спасибо

Comment: Да, скорее всего кавычек не хватает, но в любом случае лучше правильным образом параметры подставлять, а не "вручную"